# Is there a better/more efficient way to store then large arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm opening a text file which can hold anywhere between 100 and 50,000 dataFrames, and assigning each line of the txt file to a dataFrame, where a dataFrame is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
  double azimuth;
  double elevation;
  double roll;
} dataFrame;
```

I need the data to be accessible so that I can plot it in a graph in qwt, (which means I'll need to create various other arrays from the data as well for instantaneous velocity etc.) but I'm a bit worried since I don't know how much this is gonna slow down the system.
Currently, I read the number of lines, and then have

```
dataFrame*  left;
dataFrame*  right;
left = new dataFrame[lineCount/2];
right= new dataFrame[lineCount/2];
```

and then procede to fill it up as the data is read from the txt file.

Comment: Efficient for ***what***? Memory? Access time? Insertions? Deletions? Search?

Comment: 50k*6*64bits is 2.4Mb. That's not a lot of memory if you're not on an embedded system.

Comment: If you're worried about how to **store** binary data so you can read it efficiently, perhaps you'll find the [NetCDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) library/format useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need fast indexing and you know the number of elements (`lineCount`) up front, nothing beats a good old array.*

If you also want fast appending, use a dynamic array such as `std::vector` or `QVector`.

If you want fast searching for an item by key, check out `std::set`, `std::map`, `QSet`, `QHash`.

[*] Almost nothing. Post your alternatives in the comments.

Comment: If we know the size upfront, then vector is no different to arrays.

Comment: @Jagannath: except that it may overallocate.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::list<dataFrame>`. It doesn't attempt to allocate contiguous memory. If you are looking for more background info, try to find a brief summary of basic data structures (array, linked list, various trees) and their tradeoffs in memory/access/deletion/insertion performance.

Comment: A `std::deque` would give faster lookups though.  Assuming `operator[]` would be handy for graph drawing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your concern is memory usage since you're talking about a large dataset. I don't think there is a much more efficient way (memory wise) to store it than an array. The overhead per `dataFrame` is only the pointer to it. Unless you're using the stack that overhead is unavoidable and you shouldn't use the stack for large datasets due to its limited size.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking about memory usage. I guess I kinda had stack limits lurking at the back of my mind.